# How can I make my "TM" smaller?

Tags: silverlight, fonts, symbols

I'm working on a Silverlight 4 application. I have a "TM" symbol embedded in the resource string for my application's name so that wherever it appears in text the "TM" sits beside it.  Well, my client says he likes it and wants to keep it but says that the "TM" is too big.  I'm wondering if I can fix this without breaking my resource system.  I'm not using Microsoft's Resx because it has always caused random exceptions and baffling compiler errors for me even when used straight out of the box (i.e. with the Silverlight Business Application template -- I take it out first thing). I'm using my own proprietary string resource solution which is fairly simple and uses attached dependency properties to inject strings from an XML store.

Something like this:

```
<TextBox res:Strings.Assignment="Text=HomeView.Title" />
```

And here is the relevant part of the XML store:

```
<Group Name="Default">
    <Resource Name="ApplicationName"><![CDATA[MyApp™]]></Resource>
</Group>
<Group Name="HomeView">
    <Resource Name="Title"><![CDATA[Welcome to [~ApplicationName]]]></Resource>
</Group>
```

As you can see one resource can reference another.  And the "TM" is embedded straight into the `Default.ApplicationName` resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the appearance of special symbols is defined by the font itself, so short of editing the font, you'll just have to make a separate section like RobSiklos mentioned

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
<TextBox>
  <Run res:Strings.Assignment="Text=HomeView.Title" /><Run FontSize="8" Text="(tm)"/>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I know its unlikely, but I'm looking for more of a fine tuning to the the rules of superscript characters or something.  I suppose there isn't a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

```
<RichTextBox res:Strings.Assignment="Xaml=HomeView.Title" />
```

So you're setting the Xaml property of a RichTextBox.  That way you should be able to put in all the formatting you want, I would guess.  Haven't actually tried it though.